# How to get data from sub collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore Collection

[image]

I am trying to get data from sub collection but unable to get it I have provide the query that I have written down below

```
 getSchedules() async {
    var schedules = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('doctors')
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('doctors')
            .doc(element.id)
            .collection('schedules')
            .where("docid", isEqualTo: element.id)
            .get();
      });
    });
    mapRecords(schedules);
  }
```

Comment: This pattern is really read-expensive. If your database grows you'll get a very high invoice. Beside that, why do you check for a docid? since the schedules subcollection is nested inside the doctor document, how can a schedule not be of that doctor?

Comment: basically Its an admin panel and i want to show schedules with specific doctor schedule on user side app..  I tried with collection group that shows every single schedule collection data to all over the doctors details

Comment: Sorry man, I didn't get that. Could you explain better what you want to do?

Comment: its an doctor appointment app where a doctor set his schedule time for appointments and when I am try to show that schedule  in  doctor details on user side app in doctor profile

Comment: I tried collection group but it shows schedule every doctor profile even they did not set the schedule

Comment: If you are inside an app that is personal for a doctor, then you should have his uid, without cycling externally. Again, I think that you should probably review your data structure within firestore. Why don't you put the schedules as a Map inside the doctor document? Then you can create a Model class in flutter and assign the schedules to it, as a List<Schedule> in your Doctor main model

Comment: If the schedules of every doctor should be public (so a patient can See them) I suggest to create a collection at root  level, where doctors can write and patients can read. It's, indeed, another data structure change 

Comment:  I just started the firebase actually a beginner.

Comment: My suggestion for you is to review your data structure and act as I wrote in the comments above. And read VERY VERY CAREFULLY firebase docs on how pricing works, since making a mistake and going bankrupt is a matter of seconds if you're not aware of what you are doing. On the other side, if everything is under control, trust me there's no better choice for serverless development

Answer (score 0):

You are in an async method there is no reason to use that  pattern..

first  await  for doctor list
then use FOR instead of  FOR EACH and cycle through the doctor list and retrieve for  every doctor the schedule. something like this

var all_schedules

var doctors = await get doctors

for(var doctor in doctors.docs)

all_schedules merge await get schedules for this doctor